# Create an Audio Graphic Equalizer for Windows

Tags: winforms, winapi, audio, signal-processing

I need to create an **audio graphic equalizer** with the commonly used **presets**, for an application in Windows. I need to **apply the equalization effects globally** across all applications in Windows (ex DFX audio enhancer v11.1 applies effects at system level).

Currently I can get to the frames of the system audio using sAPO samples provided by Microsoft. But I need to apply graphic equalization to this.

Does Microsoft provides **any API or Sample code** for creating graphic equalizer in Windows?

Kindly inform me if there are any **other Libraries or Open Source** project that I can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say whether your sticky point is creating the audio filters or injecting your audio in to the system's audio stream. I can only offer some insight about the filtering part.

In an abstract sense, a graphic equalizer is a set of notch filters, each one tuned to a specific frequency. Center your EQ on 1KHz (1000 Hz) and go up and down in factors of 2. For example: 31, 62, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000

The best eq system is a set parametric eq's. A parametric EQ lets you set the specific frequency of each filter, and a good parametric EQ plugin will let you set as many or as few filters as you need.

So what you need to build is a programmable notch filter, then stack them to get as many bands as you need.

I would start by seeing what the open source programs do: [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is one: you can explore the equalization and audio filter plugins to see if they meet your requirements.

Some Google searching also turned up this resource: http://music.columbia.edu/cmc/music-dsp/

I hope that helps get you started (at least on the filtering part.) If you figure out how to write a real-time filter that can directly inject itself in to the Windows sound architecture, let us know.