# Implement Equalizer to C# Music Player

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, audio-player, equalizer

I have made a music player in C# WinForms, all going good. Now I want to add an equalizer interface(the vertical sliders that change bass, treble, etc), just like Winamp's EQ, but I can't find anthing on the net.

To clear any doubts about what I mean, look this picture:
[image]

That's it. I don't need all the bands, I need at least 5 or 6.

Thanks in Advance - CCB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635346/create-an-audio-graphic-equalizer-for-windows

Comment: @JeffOrris that post did not help me too much. I need to see a sample code. Paramethric EQ is a good idea, but I still don't know how to attach this to a simple trackbar or slider.

Comment: This might help:  http://lakeofsoft.com/vcx/equalizer.html

Comment: It's a .NET 2.0 or 3.0, cannot implement it to my app since it has some other libraries that I don't know where to download them.